# Drupal Feed Import module uninstall issue

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I tried to disable and uninstall Feed Import module 7.x-3.4. But after uninstallation, I can still find it in the module list. What should I do to remove it completely from the module list? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should delete all the files and folders associated with it. Depending on how it was installed, it might be in sites/all/modules.